# QTextEdit for input and output

Tags: c++, qt

I am considering using [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html) as console-like IO element (for serial data). 
The problem with this approach is that (user) input and (communication) output are mixed and they might not be synchronous.

To detect new user input, it might be possible to store and compare `plainText` on certain input events, e.g. when Enter/Return is pressed.

Another approach might be to use the QTextEdit as view only for separately managed input and output buffers. This could also simplify the problem of potentially asynchronous data (device sends characters while user is typing, very unlikely in my case).
However, even merging the two "streams" by single-character timestamp holds potential for conflict.

Is there a (simple) solution or should I simply use separate and completely independent input/output areas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate I/O areas is the simplest way to proceed if your UI is command driven and the input is line-oriented.

Alternatively, the remote device can be providing the echo, without a local echo. The remote device will then echo the characters back when it makes sense, to maintain coherent display.

You can also display a local line editing buffer to provide user feedback in case the remote echo was delayed or unavailable. That buffer would be only for feedback and have no impact on other behavior of the terminal; all keystrokes would be immediately sent to the remote device.